# Can you use logistic regression on predictors that are binary (0 or 1)

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data

How well does logistic regression behave with a large number of predictor variables that are all binary?

So say p > 1000 (number of predictors)
and the Range(p) = 0 or 1

Comment: I guess it would work to some extend, probably also depending on how balanced your outcomes are. But why don't you give a bit of info as to why you'd do this i the first place as opposed to use a more suitable model?

Comment: Why wouldn't logistic regression work in this case? There is no assumption on the predictors in the logistic regression model, they are just known constants?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, that's what I thought but then the other commenter seems to be saying that logistic regression may not be the best suited?

Comment: @sheß well I have a binary classification problem where all my predictors (several thousand) are all binary ... thoughts?

Comment: As long as p < n you should be fine. Your model will be something like $\log{\frac{\mu_0}{\mu_0+\mu_1}}=x\beta$. In fact, the results will be exactly the same as if you passed your data in a grouped form BUT you cannot use the deviance to assess your model fit. You can use the LRT, but not the deviance.